# How to avoid placing the desk facing a wall, if a window is facing the door?

Tags: office-layout, ergonomics

Below is a sketch of my current office room layout. The desk and the bookshelves can be moved.

[image: sketch of office room layout]

According to the article ["Where to Put Your Desk" on What's Best Next](https://www.whatsbestnext.com/2009/10/where-to-put-your-desk/), it is generally best to see the door from your desk. This is difficult to do in my office, since the window will be at the back and reflection will be a problem.

The article ["What If My Desk Is Facing A Wall?" on Open Spaces Feng Shui](http://openspacesfengshui.com/feng-shui-tips/2010/02/feng-shui-office-command-position/) suggests not to put the desk facing a wall.

Is there a better arrangement that can follow the above principles?

Comment: "Better" in terms of what?

Comment: The way your desk is placed now is in adherence with [German office workplace ergonomics regulations](http://publikationen.dguv.de/dguv/pdf/10002/215-410.pdf) (long document, in German but has pictures). The desk should be perpendicular to the window, there should be a light source overhead the desk.

Comment: as @simbabque has cited, there are general guidelines on how to place things to achieve best ergonomy of the workplace. If *office-layout* is on-topic here, I don´t see why this question isn´t?

Comment: This question fits the definition of navigating the workplace, and is on-topic. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Is this your home office or your commercial building office?

Comment: Would it be pedantic to point out that you have East and West reversed in your sketch?

Comment: Crazy idea:  Move the desk around till you find a position that works

Comment: @Lumberjack - Not if he's drawn if from the perspective of lying on the floor looking up ;)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest a small alteration to your layout per below picture.

[image: Proposed layout]

Place your chair at or near position C1. This satisfies all your requirements:

1. Your desk is perpendicular to the window with less of the window behind the desk, so there is less reflection.
2. You can see the door without tilting your neck too much.
3. Your desk is not directly facing a wall, so you don't feel boxed in.

**Additional usecases**:

- Collaborate with your coworkers by pulling in chair(s) at position C2 (and C3).
- Attend conference calls from one place by placing additional chairs at C2, C3, C4, C5, C6.
- Have face-to-face meetings (one-on-one meeting with a subordinate or an interview candidate) by placing a chair at or near position C5.
- Draw <s>doodles</s> diagrams on the whiteboard (together with coworkers when required), which you can look at later while working at your desk.

Comment: Upvote for putting effort into a diagram!

Comment: @dwizum That's the power of Powerpoint Fu. :)

Answer (score 4):

Close to the power outlets and out of the sun.  However, if you're in the northern hemisphere, the sun won't matter too much.

The power outlets are the key director here - placing the desk away from power outlets will result in extension cords trailing on the floor around the edge of the room.  Extension cords also increase the risk of fuses getting blown if you put too much current draw onto one plug.  Your building maintenance department won't like that.

Comment: power outlets, network connections, ...